# Lambda function to calculate mean of mean

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

My dataframe has 2 levels of index and I can calculate mean value for each primary index using the mean of mean method `mean2 = df.groupby(level=['index1']).mean().mean(axis=1)`.
I saw another method using lambda function and it results the same value. I just can't understand what is going on inside the  `apply(lambda)`.

Any explanation is very much appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
arrays = [
    np.array(["bar", "bar", "baz", "baz", "foo", "foo", "qux", "qux"]),
    np.array(["one", "two", "one", "two", "one", "two", "one", "two"]),
]
s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(8), index=arrays)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4), index=arrays)
df.index.names = ['index1', 'index2']
df


#Method 1: Mean for the whole date
mean1 = df.groupby(level='index1').apply(lambda cormat: cormat.values.mean())
# MEthod 2: Mean of mean
mean2 = df.groupby(level=['index1']).mean().mean(axis=1)

print(mean1,mean2)
```

Comment: Hint: look at `type(cormat.values)`.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's consider the following data and see the output:

```
data = {
    1 : [10,20,15,15],
    2 : [10,12,11,11]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

mean = df.apply(lambda x: x.mean())
print(mean)
```

Output:

```
1    15.0
2    11.0
```

As you know, generally, it can be said that lambda is a kind of `for` on rows. (I don't know how scientifically correct I am, but this is what I feel)
That's why many times when we want to perform `for` on the dataframe (especially when we deal with conditional expressions) we use lambda.
When we run something like `df.apply(lambda x: x.mean())` it means to move on the row and give the mean of the row

This is your dataframe:

```
                      0         1         2         3
index1 index2                                        
bar    one    -0.670105  0.007948  1.016790  0.539176
       two     0.025020  0.751342 -0.402003 -1.279099
baz    one    -0.379699  1.834577 -0.106809 -0.105114
       two     0.341889  0.697291  0.640217 -0.264288
foo    one     0.985640  1.079954 -1.079756 -0.252929
       two     0.559913  1.254874 -0.387722 -0.992791
qux    one    -0.192437 -0.522757 -0.638837  1.826321
       two    -2.106791 -0.280402  0.593201  0.824298
```

With this code, we have the following output:

```
#Method 1: Mean for the whole date
mean1 = df.groupby(level='index1').apply(lambda x: x.mean())

# MEthod 2: Mean of mean
mean2 = df.groupby(level=['index1']).mean().mean(axis=1)

print(mean1,'\n-----------------------------------------------\n',mean2)
```

Output:

```
               0         1         2         3
index1                                        
bar    -0.322543  0.379645  0.307393 -0.369962
baz    -0.018905  1.265934  0.266704 -0.184701
foo     0.772776  1.167414 -0.733739 -0.622860
qux    -1.149614 -0.401579 -0.022818  1.325309 
-----------------------------------------------
 index1
bar   -0.001367
baz    0.332258
foo    0.145898
qux   -0.062175
dtype: float64
```

So it seems, based on the second index, the mean were calculated.

With the code below, it becomes clear how `values` works.

```
values = df.groupby(level='index1').apply(lambda x: x.values)
print(values[0])
```

Output:

```
[[-0.6701054   0.00794845  1.01678958  0.5391757 ]
 [ 0.02501959  0.75134187 -0.40200268 -1.27909938]]
```

Now maybe it makes sense a little better:

```
#Method 1: Mean for the whole date
mean1 = df.groupby(level='index1').apply(lambda x: x.values.mean())

# MEthod 2: Mean of mean
mean2 = df.groupby(level=['index1']).mean().mean(axis=1)

print(mean1,'\n-----------------------------------------------\n',mean2)
```

Ouput:

```
index1
bar   -0.001367
baz    0.332258
foo    0.145898
qux   -0.062175
dtype: float64 
-----------------------------------------------
 index1
bar   -0.001367
baz    0.332258
foo    0.145898
qux   -0.062175
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, `lambda`s are anonymous functions; thus, it has no different than having a separate function, such as:

```
def first_mean(cormat):
    return cormat.values.mean()


mean1 = df.groupby(level='index1').apply(first_mean)
```

In the anonymous function: `lambda cormat: cormat.values.mean()`

- `cormat`: argument name
- `cormat.values.mean()`: return value

In other words, `cormat` is just a name. For example, I use `x` (even though it is not good for code readability).

The reason to use `lambda`s is convenience. This guy just didn't bother himself to define a separate function to calculate the first mean and passed a `lambda`.

From the `pandas` perspective, `.groupby()` method returns an iterable (a `list` of `tuple`s), and `.apply()` method applies the function to each of small part of the iterable. In other words, you can write the whole `.apply(lambda ...)` part as follow:

```
def first_mean(cormat):
    return cormat.values.mean()


groups = df.groupby(level='index1')
t_dfs = []  # container to store each processed chunk of groupby
for name, group in groups:
    t_dfs.append(first_mean(group))

result = pd.concat(t_dfs)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

From GroupBy.apply [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

> The function passed to apply must take a dataframe as its first
> argument

Function that you provide to `apply()` takes the whole group's dataframe as an argument. So calling `values.mean()` will calculate the mean across all rows/columns of the group. In method #1 you group dataframe by first index, then for each group you calculate mean across all rows/values within each group and then the result is joined together in a Series.